# What is the relation between density matrices and phase-space probability distributions?

Tags: density-matrix, cq-states, wigner-function, probability

According to its [tag description](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density-matrix), a **density matrix** is the quantum-mechanical analogue to a **phase-space probability measure** (probability distribution of position and momentum) in classical statistical mechanics.

How can I reconcile the concept and intuition behind a "probability distribution based on both position and momentum" found in statistical mechanics, with that of a matrix ensemble of 1's and 0's found in the quantum density matrix?

Comment: The assertion in the first paragraph is false. A good analogue to the phase-space probability distribution is the [Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution), not the density matrix.

Comment: The assertion was written into the tag for "density-matrix". should someone correct it https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density-matrix

Comment: Yes, someone should correct it.

Comment: I edited the tags. Note that there is also a discrete analogue of the Wigner function for finite-dimensional systems. Anyway, would you reformulate/state your question more precisely?

Comment: i didn't mean edit the tag in the question, but edit the tag tag's description in the link i gave

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I completely misread your sentence. You can certainly debate this assertion. But I guess this should happen in Meta.

Comment: I would say that the "quantum-mechanical analogue" to a phase-space distribution would be a *quasiprobability distribution*, not a density matrix. A density matrix, like a state, gives you the amplitude in a single basis (say, the position *or* the momentum). You need to use something like a [Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) for a description in terms of phase-space variables. Unless you mean something more specific with "quantum-mechanical analogue" here.

Comment: no one has fixed the density-matrix tag's description yet?

Comment: @glS well, as I said, one can certainly debate this. Nevertheless, the quasiprobability distribution has to origin from a quantum state, which is not the case for an arbitrary one (psd constraint!). Thus, the "quantum-mechanical analogue" are those distributions coming from quantum states which are 1-to-1 with quantum states. It's just a matter of representation. In the end, the density matrix contains the information about the state of the system, as does the phase space measure in the classical case.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich actually it seems to me like we are saying the same thing. I agree that they are both equally valid representations for a physical state. I don't see why the possibility of describing finite-dimensional systems with quasiprobability distributions affects this statement

Comment: @glS I just wanted to point out that while probability measures on phase space are always valid *classical* states, quasiproability measures are not necessarily valid quantum states. Thus saying that they are the quantum analogue is not entirely correct. But I agree that this point of view is often helpful. I'm working in the (discrete) phase space picture the whole day ;)